# How to place 2 divs next to each other, display:inline-box is not working

Tags: html, css

I have two an issue with aligning two `<div>` next to each other using CSS.

Below is an image showing the header and two boxes. How can I get the green boxes on the same line?
[image: image of boxes]

I've tried using `display: inline-block`, but it's not working as expected.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwv347Lz/13/)

```css
        header {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            color: #919191;
            padding: 15px;
            line-height: 30px;
            max-width: calc(770px - 30px);
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .container {
            max-width: 770px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 15px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .left, .right {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin-right: 10px;
            background-color: #58C5B3;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            vertical-align: top;
        }


        .left-header, .right-header {
            font-size: 10px;
            padding: 15px;
        }

        .left-text, .right-text {
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        FORSIDEN
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="left-header">
                BORDER-LEFT
            </div>
            <div class="left-text">
                One two three four five six seven eight nine ten
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="right-header">
                BORDER-RIGHT
            </div>
            <div class="right-text">
                One two three four five six seven eight nine ten
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have no idea what's up with your code, because I can't actually properly change any of it via Firebug, but you have an inner-div in the `#topp_r` div, which has margins flowing out of the containing div, which will lead to other divs placed next to it, not lining up. But for the container (the green/white one), it would be better to create one container div, and then have two containers within that div, instead of having a top and bottom without anything to hold them together.

Comment: Have a look on the css `display` property and more specifically to the `flex` value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example. I did not use any of your css, as the html and those things are missing, but hopefully this can get you going:

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden; /*To get your parent to respect the floated divs*/
}

.one, .two, .three {
    position: relative;
    width: 33.33333333333333%; /*Because you only have 3 elements (100 divided by 3)*/
    height: 100px;
    float: left; /*To get them next to each other if all else fails*/
    background: green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one">
        Div One
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        Div Two
    </div>
    <div class="three">
        Div Three
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I tried to replicate your website to what I think you are trying to explain :).

Here's a quick screenshot:

[image]

Please see this HTML and CSS to replicate the image above :):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cocos - Audun Hilden</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
                background: #36536B;
            }

            header {
                background: #FFFFFF;
                color: #919191;
                padding: 15px;
                line-height: 30px;
                max-width: calc(770px - 30px);
                border-radius: 3px;
                margin: auto;
            }

            .container {
                max-width: 770px;
                margin: auto;
                margin-top: 15px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .left, .right {
                float: left;
                overflow: hidden;
                border-radius: 3px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                max-width: calc(50% - 5px);
            }
            .right {
                margin-right: 0px;
            }

            .left-header, .right-header {
                background: #58C5B3;
                font-size: 10px;
                padding: 15px;
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }

            .left-text, .right-text {
                background: #FFFFFF;
                padding: 5px;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            FORSIDEN
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="left">
                <div class="left-header">
                    BORDER-LEFT
                </div>
                <div class="left-text">
                    One two three four
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="right-header">
                    BORDER-RIGHT
                </div>
                <div class="right-text">
                    One two three four five six seven
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Take some time to look at the HTML and CSS to try figure out what is going on. Once you understand, you'll never forget!

Comment: Thanks!, but on my website, you can see that where the text is, its another background. How do you do that?

Comment: @apility, sorry, I'm not clear on what you are asking :). Can you please ellaborate?

Comment: @apility, please see my edited answer. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Fredrik Moller, looks dope! Fixed this: http://audunhilden.tk/projects/temp/, but how do you get the boxes to stay to  my wrapper? <pre>.wrapper {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px;</pre>

Comment: @apility, can you ellaborate? What do you want to achieve? Do you want the 3 boxes on the bottom to stretch? Explain :) Don't be afraid to type too much, more text can make me understand LOL

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that your doctype is also invalid. Try using `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Your code is all over the place too. You have html code outside of the body. The style tag should be inside the head tag, but ideally you should be using a stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

I just added  `display: inline;` to the  #tekst-sett div id in the css

and added acontainer to both inputs as you requested.

```
<div id="cont">
<div id="tekst-sett">
        Insert text pls
    </div>

<div id="tekst-sett">
        Insert text pls
    </div>
</div>





#tekst-sett {
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-left: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-right: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 24%;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline;
}
```

is that what you meant?
[image]

Comment: Using the inline display mode isn't a good solution for this. Inline removes the ability to use height, width, margin and other important CSS properties. Use inline-block instead, or better yet, use floats.

Comment: in that case float:left as @Frederik Moller suggested is the best case.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use the concept of Flex to achieve this. Here is the small example of what you are expecting

```css
#main{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-around;  
}
#sub1,#sub2{
width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="sub1">
  </div>
<div id="sub2">
  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, are you able to set another box inside it? just like i did. For the title.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use floats, and maybe do a little research it will be easier next time if you solve it yourself!
I recommend you this article, maybe it will help you some further project:
https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/